# Add text to a span within multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html content in which a span tag is placed inside multiple div tags.

For example :

```
<div id="ae_launcher" class="module tipsytip active" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="" style="display: none;" original-title="">
    <div class="left">
        <span class="copy-narrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, please note the class "ae-left" has been used 3 times in the entire page.

I need to add text inside the span tag.

I tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.left:eq(1) .copy-narrow').text('hidshjgdjb');
</script>
```

But this din't solve the issue.

Comment: `$('.ae-copy-narrow').text('your text here');` ...?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it via jQuery

```
$('#ae_launcher .ae-left > span ').text("Hello");
```

Comment: This din't work the problem being class .ae-left is used multiple times, how to make the code traverse to the 2nd or 3rd element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used ae-left div class as the parent of the span in all the 3 places

```
$('.ae-left span ').text("Text here");
```

Comment: the problem here is .ae-left class is used multiple times

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var l = document.getElementsByClassName("ae-copy-narrow");
                l[x].innerHTML = "some text";

</script>
```

x is the location you want to place between 0-2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

`$('.left > .copy-narrow').text("your Text");`

This will set the innerText property of all elements with 
    `.copy-narrow`
class to `your Text`.
If you want to select this particular span only, you can always use the id attribute of the parent div as id attribute must be unique.

```
$('#ae_launcher .copy-narrow').text('your text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `class` and use the `.text()`:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var sometext = 'This is my text';
        $('.ae-copy-narrow').text(sometext);
    });
</script>
```

Or if you want to have html tags you can use `.html()`:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var sometext = '<img src="myimage.png" />';
        $('.ae-copy-narrow').html(sometext);
    });
</script>
```